# jQuery change doesn't work on IE

Tags: jquery

```
if (jQuery(select).hasClass('super-attribute-select')) {
   jQuery(select).on('change', function() {
     alert('select babe');
   });
}
```

The `onChange` seems to not fire in IE, the function `recreate_swatches_recursive(select)` is not called. It is called in Chrome and Firefox. I've tried several solutions including:

1. change `on.('change')` > `live('click change')`
2. change `on.('change')` > `change(handler)`

Is there any work around to make this code works in IE ? I've done some searchings but still get stuck at this :(

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work. What happens?

Comment: the handler code is not fired in IE when I change the select's value.

Comment: what is your element type? what do you really want from change?

Comment: is the select added dynamically? If so you have to add the event once again or set the delgation on the wrapping element

Comment: Change is fired when you focus out (blur) the select. Are you testing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Change `hasClassName` to `hasClass` and it should work!

```
if (select.hasClass('super-attribute-select')) {
```

The execution never passes the initial `if` condition and thus the `change` event is not bound to the select element.

Comment: `hasClassName()` is part of the prototype framework. The fact that the OP states that the code works in Chrome/Firefox suggests that this method is available, and that this isn't the cause of the problem

Comment: The question is tagged under `jQuery` and not under `Prototype`; `jQuery` uses `hasClass()` instead of `hasClassName()`.

Comment: sorry for confusing you, actually this part of code is rewritten from prototype because I think the `observe` function in prototype doesn't work properly.
I have to use a small [snippet]( https://gist.github.com/3653081#file_down_prototype_equivalent.js) to implement the same `down()` function in prototype.
but somehow I still can use hasClassName, I haven't dig on this part yet. But I've updated the code to wrap jQuery around the element to make sure it doesn't confuse people.